# Ubuntu One: "The user cancelled a prompt."

Tags: ubuntu-one, password, keyrings, gnome-keyring

Every time that I try to sign in to Ubuntu One, it tells me:

```
"An application wants to create a new keyring called 'default'. Choose the password you want to use for it."
```

I set the password to nothing, confirm that I was to use unsafe storage, and then I'm not signed in, with Ubuntu One telling me, `The user cancelled a prompt`

How do I get rid of this so I can use Ubuntu One ?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up on [Ubuntu One official website](http://one.ubuntu.com) and sign in back on ubuntu one desktop application